# Jquery Cannot get datepicker value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

on this code:

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom1" name="dateFrom1" class="form-control datePicker"/>
            <i class="ace-icon1 fa fa-calendar"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datePicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

When i submit a form, params.dateFrom1 hold value of datePicker.
However, when I used this way, I cannot get value of datePicker

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom1" name="dateFrom1" class="form-control datePicker" disabled/>
            <i class="ace-icon1 fa fa-calendar" onclick="showPicker('#dateFrom1')"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datePicker').datepicker();

    function showPicker(ele) {
        $(ele).datepicker('show');
    }
</script>
```

The fact is that input box shows value after I picked date, and when I `alert($('#dateFrom1'))` I also alerted value of date but when I submit form, I get `null` value

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: looks good and should work! provide any link to the problem?

Comment: you are not getting value in jquery or not on server side

Comment: not on server side, on client side, it still shows date value on textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5Kp/)**

1. You are defining `.datepicker()` function on `.datePicker` class.
   And in `showPicker()` you were passing `#dateFrom1`, the datePicker
   considers this as undefined.
2. Also, wrap your datepicker initialisation code in `$(document).ready(..)`

---

**HTML** :

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom1" name="dateFrom1" class="form-control datePicker" disabled/>
<i class="ace-icon1 fa fa-calendar" onclick="showPicker('.datePicker')">Icon</i>
```

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.datePicker').datepicker();
});
function showPicker(ele) {
    $(ele).datepicker('show');
}
```

*Suggestion* : Also, if you are using jQuery, I would suggest you use jQuery `.click()` instead of inline `onclick=".."`

Comment: Thanks for answer, as I mentioned above, I got date value on textbox, but on server side, params. dateFrom1 = null

Comment: Hey guys, I found that error, it was my fault, when input has property disabled, it sends nothing. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this code  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manjeshpv/h26P8/)

```
<input type="text" id="dateFrom1" name="dateFrom1" class="form-control datePicker" disabled/>
<i class="ace-icon1 fa fa-calendar" id="button" onclick="showPicker('#dateFrom1')">button</i>
<script>
$(function () {

    $('.datePicker').datepicker();
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $("#dateFrom1").datepicker('show');

    });


});
</script>
```